# Zooming an image working with view image and not with the below code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I'm trying to show an image, where when you zoom in on a particular spot, it should display that particular area completely on the screen. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYMc5/). I want to view the image to be of the same resolution as shown in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYMc5/), but when I zoom in, the magnified zone of the picture should fill the entire original picture frame.

Below is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>

    <style>
        /* styles unrelated to zoom */
                body {
    background-color: black;
    margin:0 auto;
}
        * { border:0; margin:0; padding:0; }
        p { position:absolute; top:3px; right:28px; color:#555; font:bold 13px/1 sans-serif;}

        /* these styles are for the demo, but are not required for the plugin */
        .zoom {
            display:inline-block;
            position: relative;
                        background-color: black;                        
                        z-index:1000;
        }

        /* magnifying glass icon */
        .zoom:after {
            content:'';
            display:block; 
            width:50px; 
            height:50px; 
            position:relative; 
            top:50;
            right:70;

        }

        .zoom img {
            display: block;
        }

        .zoom img::selection { background-color: transparent; }

        #ex3 img:hover { cursor:-moz-zoom-in; }

    </style>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/jquery.zoom.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#ex3').zoom({ on:'toggle' });             

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <span class='zoom' id='ex3'>
    <img src='images/cg_layout.jpg' width='918' height='655' alt=''>

    </span>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
The above code works fine in zooming in a particular place now, when I click on view image in Firefox, I can see zoom work there also, and it works perfectly as I want it. What can I do to make zoom work like as in view image.
**EDIT1** 
Now when I click on view image in Firefox, I can zoom this image. When I click the zoom the image the class changes from **`shrinktofit`** to **`overflowing`**. When I do the next click the image zoomouts from **`overflowing`** to **`shrinktofit`**. Now how can Get this feature embedded with my image

Comment: not working because Git Refused to execute script, you just remove that link and download it to local,it'll work fine, Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/hYMc5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation of the zoom, it's not click but directly hover (A build off of what Hardik did).

http://jsfiddle.net/4CHj2/1/

You can also different examples used here:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

Note that there is an external resource hosted on Drive that Hardik attached to his fiddle. 
With that code, you are free to test any example on the site as is.

```
Good Luck!
```